# How to close a popup without an "X" button

Tags: browser

I have a popup window that has arrived unbidden, It has no "close" button of its own.  Furthermore, it refuses to close at all without taking down any open tab in my browser with it.  Then once I reopen the browser, everything comes back--including the offending popup window--much as if nothing had ever happened at all.
I hate working within the confines of software that has been designed poorly, if not outright maliciously.
I might add that the URL for this offending popup does not show up separately on its own.

I refer you to the details of my problem.  Originally that was in a separate field; however, now the two files have been merged.  And I was expecting the popup window to close, without taking anything else with it.  Pretty obvious, right?  I simply have proven unable to take care of this matter entirely on my own.

Comment: I should have said "FireFox" rather than "C++."

Comment: Maybe browser is a better tag then, and looks like someone doesn't want you to be able to close it (at least I have no solution for you)